# Subject of equation with lambert-W function in multiple positions

Tags: lambert-w

Is it possible to make $x$ the subject of an equation of the form:

$aW(-e^x)+b\ln[cW(-e^x)+d]+x+h=0$

where $W(x)$ is the lambert-W function and $a,b,c,d,h$ are arbitrary constants?

Comment: Not possible, alas !